# extract data using a regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I would like to extract this data and store it in an array. But I can't seem to find the proper regular expression.

```
-- Schedd: LP0162.marin.local : <172.16.102.40:58875>
 ID      OWNER            SUBMITTED     RUN_TIME ST PRI SIZE CMD               
  13.0   JJansen          2/6  09:17   0+00:01:28 I  0   1953.1 Test.bat          
  13.1   JJansen          2/6  09:17   0+00:01:28 I  0   1953.1 Test.bat          
  13.2   JJansen          2/6  09:17   0+00:01:28 I  0   1953.1 Test.bat          
  13.3   JJansen          2/6  09:17   0+00:01:27 I  0   1953.1 Test.bat          
  13.4   JJansen          2/6  09:17   0+00:00:50 I  0   1953.1 Test.bat          
  13.5   JJansen          2/6  09:17   0+00:00:50 I  0   1953.1 Test.bat          
  13.6   JJansen          2/6  09:17   0+00:00:50 I  0   1953.1 Test.bat          
  13.7   JJansen          2/6  09:17   0+00:00:50 I  0   1953.1 Test.bat
```

It should return something like this:

```
Array
(
   [0] => array
      [0] => 13.0
      [1] => JJansen
      [2] => 2/6 09:17
      [3] => 0+00:01:28
      [4] => I
      [5] => 0
      [6] => 1953.1
      [7] => Test.bat
   [1] => array
      ...
)
...
```

Comment: explode('\t', $data); ?

Comment: The data is not separated by tabs but spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to go for a combination of reading the input per line (or exploding it on line-break) and explode it by using `preg_split()`, where you can use the regular expression `(\S+)`, @acarlon wrote.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a regex to match the words that are not whitespace then you can use

```
\S+
```

Here is the output highlighting the matches:

[image: match non whitespace]